# Location Quick Reply is now deprecated on API 4.0. Please refer to our Developer Documentation for more info

Tags: node.js, chatbot, facebook-messenger, botkit

I would like to get  Facebook messenger location as a quick reply but I can not,I'm using messenger V5. It's returning: Location Quick Reply is now deprecated on API 4.0. Please refer to our Developer Documentation for more info. I referred to Facebook developer documentation but I did not fix the bug. I need help, please !!

````
    quick_replies: [
        {

            "content_type":"location",

        },

    ]```
````

Answer (score 1):

> Location quick reply which allows people to send their location in the
>   Messenger thread will no longer be rendered. We recommend businesses
>   ask for zip code and address information within the thread. While we
>   are sunsetting the existing version of Share Location, in the coming
>   months we will be introducing new ways for people to communicate their
>   location to businesses in more valuable ways.

It is not a bug, it is just not possible as of now.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/changelog/#20190610

Comment: Thank you a lot. But I would love to know if there is another way that can be used for communicating the location with the Facebook messenger. Because I want the user to select a particular location from the map and then messenger can receive the lat and the long of the selected place.

Comment: i know, but you can only do this right now: "We recommend businesses ask for zip code and address information within the thread"