# Get the location from messenger API

Tags: facebook, location, chatbot, messenger

How can I get the location? Can you give me the object that I send? I'd like an example please.

The quick reply is not working now:

I have this error:

> "(#100) Location Quick Reply is now deprecated on API 4.0. Please refer to our Developer Documentation for more info.",

when I try to send this:

```json
{
  "recipient": {
    "id": "userid"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "To assist you better, could you please share your location?",
    "quick_replies": [
      {
        "content_type": "location",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The location for the user.
Can someone please give me what can I do?

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041142/location-quick-reply-is-now-deprecated-on-api-4-0-please-refer-to-our-developer?rq=2 We are all still waiting for some sort of answer on this

Comment: yes we are still waiting a response from facebook , i tried so many things , but there is no solution for now for this problem ! we have facebook will post something as soon as possible